# HERE Sample projects dont compile under Xcode 11.5

Tags: xcode, here-api

I am stuck with HERE SDK. I downloaded heresdk-lite-ios-4.3.3.0.2240 and opened some of the sample projects that are supplied with it (HalloMapLite, GesturesLite, RoutingLite), but none of them compiles...!

> There is no XCFramework found at
>   '/Users/claude/Downloads/heresdk-lite-ios-4.3.3.0.2240/heresdk-lite-ios-examples-4.3.3.0/HelloMapLite/heresdk.xcframework'.

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the SDK binary is missing. The SDK is not included in any example from github. You get it from the HERE developer portal where you registered (and where you get the credentials).

Please do not forget: To run the app, you need to add your HERE SDK credentials to the Info.plist file of your project. More information can be found in the Get Started section of the Developer's Guide.

Comment: actually the import heresdk is missing in their samples. Strange that they havent corrected such a simple error

Comment: The import statement seems to be there. Check this one, for example: https://github.com/heremaps/here-sdk-examples/blob/master/examples/4.3.3.0/lite/ios/HelloMapLite/HelloMapLite/ViewController.swift - maybe you can be more specific where exactly it is missing? Note that 4.3.3 is an older release. The latest release for iOS Lite can be found here: https://github.com/heremaps/here-sdk-examples/tree/master/examples/latest/lite/ios